# Iron bar set in concrete heavily corroded; how to mitigate?

Tags: concrete, corrosion

I have a decorative concrete column (solid concrete with rebar) in front of a multi-storey house, about 10m hight. Said column is held by three thick steel bars (6 x 2 cm) that link it to the house, giving it stability.

The steel bar has been heavily affected by rust right at the point where it enters the concrete column. The metal has cauliflowered. It looks like a piece from a saltwater ship. Is there some galavanic corrosion effect here?

[image: bar affected by rust]

So I have tried to clean the affected area somewhat, but it is difficult to reach (I can't even properly reach the far side) and I'm not sure how far the rust reaches into the column. I have managed to reach this point:

[image: bar cleaned up somewhat, pic 1]

Admire the multiple layers of paint. I have counted a primer and 4 layers on top.

[image: bar cleaned up somewhat, pic 2]

How to proceed from here? I wanted to try to clean it up some more, then use a paint that can reduce the remaining rust, put enamel on it and try to fill the hole with filler. I will not be a perfect fix.

The problem remains problematic. The two other bars are higher up and I don't know whether they are reachable at all. And I don't know how the bars look on the point where they enter the building wall. They are hidden by the outer insulation. I hate this ...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good question, great pictures; keep 'em coming!